# Angularjs does not work ng-click

Tags: angularjs

My setup is very simple

```
<button ng-click="query = ''" ng-if="query">X</button>
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
```

Check on planker but when I click on the button input is not cleaned

http://plnkr.co/edit/RTIGXFHeth4EN6GnSt8Z?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-if creates a child scope and the `ng-click ="query=''"` is set on child scope. Whereas your `ng-model=query` is defined on the parent scope.

The options are either to use `ng-show`

or pass a object property. See my fiddle here

http://plnkr.co/edit/LGmPALg4wTTmCJLE4aFa?p=preview

It would look like this

```
<body ng-app="" ng-init='query={data:""}'>
  <button ng-click="query.data = 'a'" ng-if="query.data">X</button>
    <input type="query" ng-model="query.data">
</body>
```

Also spend some time of understanding the prototype inheritance in angularjs scope https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Actualy it is simplified version. But in my controller I have `$scope.query = ''` for initialization. Because I need to have access to input value there. How it should be then?

Comment: I have managed it by using `ng-show`, but I still what to understand what is the difference.

Comment: As i said ng-if creates a new child scope, and when you set `ng-click="query=''"`, you are setting a variable on the new scope, not the query property on parent scope. Look at the wiki and use batarang extension for chrome with your old example, you would see the scopes and the properties defined on it.

Comment: Thank you for batarang! I had no idea about that. :)